# After upgrade attempting to get artifact results in "Could not process download request: Binary provider has no content for"

Tags: artifactory

I recently upgraded our artifactory repository from 2.6.5 to the current version 5.4.6.

However, something seems to have gone wrong in the process.  There are some artifacts that throw a HTTP 500 error when attempting to access them.  Here is an example using wget:

```
wget http://xyz.server.com:8081/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.0.12/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.0.12.pom
--2017-09-12 12:17:13--
http://xyz.server.com:8081/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/2.0.12/build-info-extractor-gradle-2.0.12.pom
Resolving xyz.server.com (xyz.server.com)... 10.125.1.28
Connecting to xyz.server.com (xyz.server.com)|10.125.1.28|:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2017-09-12 12:17:13 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

I verified this by going to the artifactory site, browsing to the object in question, and trying to download it.  The result was the following:

```
{
    "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Could not process download request: Binary provider has no content for 'e52a9a9a58d6829b7b13dd841af4b027c88bb028'"
    } ]
}
```

The problem seems to be in the final step of the upgrade process, upgrading from 3.9.5 to 5.4.6.  The wget command above works on 3.9.5, but not on the 5.4.6 instance.

I found a reference to a "Zap Cache" function in older documentation and thought it might fix things, but I don't seem to be able to find that function in the current site.

Is anyone able to point me to: a way to fix this issue, or what I need to do/look for in the upgrade process in order to prevent it from occurring?

As a further data point, we're using an Oracle database for the full file store, if that matters in any way (using the tag: <chain template="full-db"> in binarystore.xml)

Thanks in advance....